# how to recover a corrupted MySQL InnoDB data file

Tags: mysql, linux, file-io

My MySQL has been crashed due to I/O issue and the InnoBD data file has been corrupted, I get the following message whenever I try to copy or move the data file:

```
cp: reading `ibdata1': Input/output error
cp: failed to extend `/root/ibdata1': Input/output error
```

I also found this error in logs:

```
mysqld: InnoDB: Error: tried to read 16384 bytes at offset 0 10665984.
mysqld: InnoDB: Was only able to read 8192.
mysqld: 150518  9:00:17  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
mysqld: InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
mysqld: InnoDB: File operation call: 'read'.
mysqld: InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should **restore** your `MySQL` databases, For do it you can use the Site Backup and Restore tool, found in the files category of your cPanel.

Comment: I don't use cPanel, and I doubt the sql restore would be possible

Comment: If you don't have a backup, you just might be #uscwoap.

Comment: I do have a backup, but any MySQL operation usually end up by this message "MySQL has gone away" or "Lost Connection"